# Couchapp returns 304 when querying a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb, couchapp

I am building a simple couchapp CRUD application. When I fetch a view, I get a 304 response from CouchDB. In futon, the same view returns documents.
Below is the snippet where I am querying the view and appending the returned items to a div. In the javascript console, I get an error saying "Can not read property _id of null"

```
db = $.couch.db("itemly");
function updateItems(){
    $("#all").empty();
    db.view("itemly/byitemname",{ success: function(data){
     for (i in data.rows){
         $("#all").append('<div id="' + data.rows[i].value._id + '" class ="itemrow"><span>'+data.rows[i].value.name + "</span><span>"+data.rows[i].value.price + "</span><span>"+data.rows[i].value.category + "</span><span>"+'<a href="#" id="'+ data.rows[i].value._id + '" class = "edit"> Edit Item </a>' +"</span><span>"+'<a href="#" id="'+ data.rows[i].value._id + '" class = "remove"> Remove Item </a>' +"</span></div>");
     }
    }
});
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. I used

```
couchapp generate view byitemname
```

to generate my view. It created a "map.js" as well as a "Reduce.js" file. I edited the map.js file according my requirement but the empty reduce.js file resulted in couchdb returning null when I fetched the view.

Note that in futon, the view "byitemname" worked properly because in futon, you have to explicitly run the reduce.js but while fetching from an app this happens automatically.

Answer (score 1):

304 means that the data is already in the cache of the browser; for your point of view it's the same as 200, only faster.

If read the error carefully, it says that the value field of the row is null. This means that you are doing something like:

```
emit("something", null);
```

in the map function of the view. Can you post your map function?

Comment: The map function was correct but I also had an empty reduce.js file in the view directly which ultimately resulted in null .